# FlashLoans contract funds are being wrongly withdrawn without any action, how is this possible?

Tags: solidity, remix, flash-loans, hack, withdrawal

I'm new with flashloan, I'm using this code to test and everything works, however the tokens that remain in the contract after 30 to 40 minutes are "stolen", "improperly withdrawn", are removed from the contract to an auto destruct contract and disappear, you can test depositing 1 USDT and 1 WMATIC in a few minutes everything is stolen without any action being taken, how is this possible?

To carry out the transaction I deposit 5 dollars of each token, everything goes fine and after a few minutes everything disappears, withdrawn by 0x60806040

**PoolAddressesProvider** 0xa97684ead0e402dC232d5A977953DF7ECBaB3CDb & 0x794a61358D6845594F94dc1DB02A252b5b4814aD

https://polygonscan.com/address/0x148f880459590b1d6939d12b07fc2e9afadd5ced#tokentxns

```
contract FlashLoan is FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase{

    event FUNDTransferred(address account, uint256 amount);
    enum dexList {
        uniswapV2,
        uniswapV3,
        paraswap,
        quickwap
    }
    uint8[] dexPath;
    address[] pairs;
    address[] currentpairs;

    address sushiSwapAddress;
    address uniswapv3Address;
    address qucikswapAddress;

    constructor(address _addressProvider, address _uniswapv3Address,address _quickswapAddress, address _sushiswapAddress) 
        FlashLoanSimpleReceiverBase(IPoolAddressesProvider(_addressProvider))
    {
       uniswapv3Address = _uniswapv3Address;
       qucikswapAddress = _quickswapAddress;
       sushiSwapAddress = _sushiswapAddress;
    }

    function withdrawFunds(address token, uint256 amount) public {
        IERC20(token).transfer(msg.sender, amount);
    }

    function swapTokens(uint256 amount) public {
        require((pairs.length) - 1 == dexPath.length, "invalid trx");

        for (uint i = 0; i < dexPath.length; i++)
        {

            if(dexList(dexPath[i]) == dexList.uniswapV3) {
                amount = uniswapV3(pairs[i], pairs[i+1], amount);
            }

            if(dexList(dexPath[i]) == dexList.paraswap) {
                amount = uniswapV3(pairs[i], pairs[i+1], amount);
            }
            
            if(dexList(dexPath[i]) == dexList.quickwap) {
                amount = quickSwap(pairs[i], pairs[i+1], amount);
            }

        }
    }

    function uniswapV3(address tokenIn, address tokenOut, uint256 amount) public returns(uint256) {

        IERC20(tokenIn).approve(uniswapv3Address, amount);
        IuniswapV3.ExactInputSingleParams memory params =
            IuniswapV3.ExactInputSingleParams({
                tokenIn: tokenIn,
                tokenOut: tokenOut,
                fee: 3000,
                recipient: address(this),
                deadline: block.timestamp + 86400,
                amountIn: amount,
                amountOutMinimum: 0,
                sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0
            });

        uint256 amountOut = IuniswapV3(uniswapv3Address).exactInputSingle(params);
        return amountOut;

    }

    function sushiswap(address tokenIn, address tokenOut, uint256 amount) public  returns(uint256[] memory) {
        IERC20(tokenIn).approve(sushiSwapAddress, amount);
        address[] memory pair = new address[](2);
        pair[1] = tokenIn;
        pair[2] = tokenOut; 
        uint256[] memory  amounts = IV2SwapRouter(sushiSwapAddress).swapTokensForExactTokens(
                amount,
                0,
                pair,
                address(this),
                block.timestamp + 86400
            );
        return amounts;
        
    }

    function quickSwap(address tokenIn, address tokenOut, uint256 amount) public returns(uint256){
        IERC20(tokenIn).approve(qucikswapAddress, amount);
        IV2SwapRouter.SushiswapParams memory params =
            IV2SwapRouter.SushiswapParams({
                tokenIn: tokenIn,
                tokenOut: tokenOut,
                recipient: address(this),
                deadline: block.timestamp + 86400,
                amountIn: amount,
                amountOutMinimum: 0,
                limitSqrtPrice: 0
            });

        uint256 amountOut = IV2SwapRouter(qucikswapAddress).exactInputSingle(params);
        return amountOut;
        
    }

    /**
        This function is called after your contract has received the flash loaned amount
     */
    function executeOperation(
        address asset,
        uint256 amount,
        uint256 premium,
        address initiator,
        bytes calldata params
    ) external override returns (bool) {
        swapTokens(amount);
        uint256 amountOwed = amount + premium;
        IERC20(asset).approve(address(POOL), amountOwed);
        return true;
    }

    function requestFlashLoan(address _token, uint256 _amount, uint8[] memory _dexList, address[] memory _pairs, uint256 profit) public {
        address receiverAddress = address(this);
        address asset = _token;
        uint256 amount = _amount;
        bytes memory params = "";
        uint16 referralCode = 0;
        dexPath = _dexList;
        pairs = _pairs;
        POOL.flashLoanSimple(
            receiverAddress,
            asset,
            amount,
            params,
            referralCode
        );

        if(profit > 0){
        IERC20(_token).transfer(msg.sender, profit);
        }
    }

    receive() external payable {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically they just call function `withdrawFunds`. You should be able to see for yourself that anyone can call that function and withdraw any tokens.

For some reason they are obfuscating the call by putting it inside a new contract (which they destroy at the end). My guess is that this way it's harder for a bot to frontrun.

Comment: Yes, I thought it was not possible to call the "Withdraw Funds" function in an obfuscated way, and that "Withdraw Funds" would always appear in the blockchain history, I didn't know it was possible to call it by hiding it when the call comes from a contract creation " SelfDestruct"